# Invoke Ansible Playbooks From Jenkins

Tags: ansible, jenkins-plugins

I'm still not figure out how to invoke Invoke Ansible Playbooks From Jenkins.
My setup:
Install Jenkin -> Install Jenkin Ansible Plugin
I found a git project: https://github.com/ricardozanini/soccer-stats.git
I'want to create a jenkin job to invoke the playbook https://github.com/ricardozanini/soccer-stats/blob/master/provision/playbook.yml, but don't know how do. Which path should I put here?
[Invoke Ansible Playbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlxlS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well you already have installed the Ansible plugin on Jenkins.

Then you can call your playbook on Jenkins file or inside your job.

```
ansiblePlaybook credentialsId: 'private_key', inventory: 'inventories/a/hosts', playbook: 'my_playbook.yml'
```

Source: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ansible+Plugin

Comment: Actually I'm new to Jenkin and Ansible. Is it correct to create a jenkin job from Jenkin UI, specify Git Repository as: https://github.com/ricardozanini/soccer-stats.git and in section  Invoke Ansible Playbook, specify Playbook path as: /provision/playbook.yml ?

Comment: Basically yes... You also need to tell Jenkins about your inventory file or fill the hosts info there... after that, just run the job and it should work fine...

Comment: Thanks Kelson Silva

Comment: In this sample, I've used the pipeline parameters to set the inventory at the "-l" flag at the Ansible plugin level. You should set your environment accordingly. If you are having difficulties to set this repo, just raise an issue at the repo and I could help you more.